# Get unique entity id from bean

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "wpf_payment_attributes")
    public class WpfPaymentAttributes implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2629784870868584850L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private int id;

        @Column(length = 32)
        private Integer wpf_payment_id;

        @Column(length = 255)
        private String name;
        ....
}
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wpf_payments")
public class WpfPayments implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5740164339503774805L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer merchant_id;
    .....
}
```

`id` is generated by the DB. I use this code to insert some data:

```
WpfPayments obj = new WpfPayments();
 obj.setReference_transaction_id(12345678);
 obj.setContract_id(contract.getId());
 obj.setMerchant_id(merchant.getId()); 
 wpfPaymentsService.saveOrUpdate(obj);

 WpfPaymentAttributes attibutes = new WpfPaymentAttributes();
 attibutes.setName("usage");
 attibutes.setValue("Test Usage");
 attibutes.setWpf_payment_id(...get here some how WpfPayments table id...id);

 wpfPaymentAttributesService.saveOrUpdate(attibutes);
```

Do you know how I can get the id from the `WpfPayments` object and save it using `attibutes.setWpf_payment_id(...)`?

Comment: Can't you use jpql query?

Comment: You have to create a OneToMany or a OneToOne relation between these two entities. IMHO the wpf_payment_id should be an instance of the wpf_payment or (depending on your answer to the first sentence) a List<Wpf_payment>.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JoinTable attributes with a setter to the entity instead of the id of WpfPayments.
The Id of WpfPayments is generated once you call the save method on the repository of this entity, just use the result of it.